# How do I add the column before running this command in t-sql?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have to write a script to update a database but im having problems doing it. The T-Sql is

```
BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION 

        ALTER TABLE company
        ADD RegistrationNumber nvarchar(50)

    COMMIT

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  IF(@@trancount > 0)
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
END CATCH



update Company set RegistrationNumber = ''
```

But im getting the error

> Invalid column name 'RegistrationNumber'.

However when I run the first bit then the second bit I dont get a problem....how do I get it all into one script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the parser analyses your query the `RegistrationNumber` field does not exist (yet) and so it reports the error; it would take a much more complex parser to recognise you are creating it earlier in the query.

Separate the two queries with `GO` and they will be parsed/executed individually, which should avoid the error.

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 
        ALTER TABLE company
        ADD RegistrationNumber nvarchar(50)
    COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  IF(@@trancount > 0)
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
END CATCH

GO -- << Add this

UPDATE Company SET RegistrationNumber = ''
```

**EDIT:** If you want both steps to be performed in one go why not just use a default value for the new column?

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 
        ALTER TABLE company
        ADD RegistrationNumber nvarchar(50) DEFAULT ''
    COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  IF(@@trancount > 0)
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
END CATCH
```

Comment: But how can I add everyting in one transaction? I want to be able to totally fail if something doesnt work

Comment: @Pete2k - transactions can span batches. If this is the desired semantics you need to remove the `commit` in your original query as well.

Comment: @Pete2k - Can I assume from your comment this is only part of a larger scrpt? If not there's not a lot to go wrong, you may as well replace your script with the single line `ALTER TABLE company ADD RegistrationNumber nvarchar(50) DEFAULT ''` and do it all in one go.